# Sort parents regarding child attribut using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model 'job' linked with the model 'job_translation' like that :

```
/**
 * Get the translations for the job.
 */
public function translations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\JobTranslation');
}
```

I want to build a dynamic api route which can accept several parameters to filter ou sorter a query on the jobs. To do that I have this kind of controller (extract) :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $queryJob = Job::query();

    // filter on the job short_name
    if ($request->has('short_name')) {
        $queryJob->where('short_name', 'ilike', '%'.$request->short_name.'%');
    }

    // filter on the translation
    if ($request->has('translation')) {
        $queryJob->whereHas('translations', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $queryJob->where('internal_translation', 'ilike', '%'.$request->translation.'%');
        });
    }

    // sort by the external translation
    if ($request->has('order.external_translation')) {
        // var_dump($request->input('order.external_translation'));
        // var_dump($request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'));

        $queryJob->whereHas('translations', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('language_id', $request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'));
            $query->orderBy('external_translation', 'asc');
        });


        /*
        $queryJob->with(['translations' => function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('language_id', $request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'));
            $query->orderBy('external_translation', 'asc');
        }]);
        */


    }


    // security for the qty of items per page
    $qtyItemsPerPage = 15;
    if ($request->has('qtyItemsPerPage')) {
        if (is_numeric($request->qtyItemsPerPage) && $request->qtyItemsPerPage <= 50) {
            $qtyItemsPerPage = $request->qtyItemsPerPage;
        }
    }

    $jobs = $queryJob->paginate($qtyItemsPerPage);

    return JobResource::collection($jobs);
```

My problem is for the sort condition (the others are OK). When I use this kind of url:

```
jobs?order[external_translation]=asc
```

I tried a lot of things without success (commented in the code), the result is never sorted like I want. I think my problem is in the relation between the two models.

So how to sort the parents regarding an attribute of their children, using Eloquent?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sort nested relationships with the query builder alone. Use the Collection's `sortBy` method instead.

Comment: Hi IGP. Thanks for your answers. It means that for my request I have to do it with a traditional queryBuilder and not Eloquent ?

Comment: No. It means you cannot use either of them to sort relationships.

Comment: When you call a relationship with `with()` or `load()`,  Eloquent executes a separate query, and then appends it to the parent. If you try to order it before it's appended, it won't do what you want.